# Android layout_above does not work on API 21

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout that contains 3 children (LinearLayout) :

- one at the top.
- one at the bottom.
- and one between the 2 last views.

The code i use for it is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="fr.caudoux.onlinegames.activities.GameMainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff44f0c3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#F01234"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_below="@id/game_main_actionbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/game_main_chat_container">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff2c3ff0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/game_main_chat_container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Since the api 21 the attribut 'android:layout_above' is not working : the second LinearLayout take all the space below the first one, and the third LinearLayout is over the second.

On api lower than 21 it works : the second part take only the space between the first and the third Linearlayout.

Does anyone known why it is not working and hos to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Alternative solution is use linear layout as root instead of Relative layout. Use android:layout_weight property in child layouts to adjust your layout accordingly. I hope this suggestion would guide you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ordering to have your top and bottom view declared before the view that is in between the two:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="fr.caudoux.onlinegames.activities.GameMainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff44f0c3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff2c3ff0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/game_main_chat_container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#F01234"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_below="@id/game_main_actionbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/game_main_chat_container">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As mentioned, this same layout is easier to do as a `LinearLayout`, which specializes in stacked elements:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="fr.caudoux.onlinegames.activities.GameMainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff44f0c3"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#F01234"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/game_main_top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff2c3ff0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/game_main_chat_container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note how only the middle element (the element that needs to fill the remaining space) has a `layout_weight` on it. This ensures that all remaining space is allocated to that view while the other views are of fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both above and below set in one view. Use below on second view and then below again on last view.

Comment: I just tried. The last view is not on the screen because the second view take all the free space.

Comment: What if you change height to wrap content on 2nd view?

Comment: Then the second view is not taking all the free space. and if a set a height in dp too big for the screen size, then the last view disappear under the screen too.

Comment: You can use linearlayout and then have three views inside it and set layout-height to 0dp for every one of them and set layout weight to .50 for middle one and .25 for top and bottom one.

Comment: But with a linearlayout and wheights i can't set the height in dp of the first and last child ?